# How to compute execution time in Nodejs ChildProcess.exec

Tags: javascript, node.js, parameters, execution-time

We have an API request that logins our users, like this:

```
...

//lauches an API request

router.post("/trip/analyse",function(req,res){

    t0 = Date.now();

    shell = ("sudo /usr/bin/python /mypythonFile");

    child = exec(shell, function (error, stdout, stderr) {

      if (error) { //There is an error

        res.json({"Error" : true});

        console.log(Date.now() - t0);  // <-------- HERE, How to get this right ?

      }else{ //everything went fine

        res.json({"Error" : false});

        console.log(Date.now() - t0);  // <-------- HERE, How to get this right ?

      }

    });

});
...
```

I see that the printed execution time is not right, because when many users login at the same time, the "t0" value used for computing the executionTime ("Date.now() - t0") is not correctly computed. It uses the t0 values of a more recent call of this API request, and not the appropriate t0 value.

This is because the exec method is asynchronous and take time to execute.

How do I right properly the execution time ("Date.now() - t0"), where the original t0 variable is lost ?

Comment: Why are the variable global ? This is probably causing your problem. Scope the variables t0 etc to the function adding var before.

Comment: Oh thank you so much !! that fixed it !!

Answer (score 1):

I only had to put

**var** t0 = Date.now();

And it worked !

Comment: Mark as solved and for best practise never use global variable in javascript.